# What landmarks would still be visible after a worldwide flood?

Tags: water

So I'm making a game about a world which is now almost entirely covered in water, and the only ones who survived are those who could find places or things like boats, rafts, or planes sticking out of the water.

The gameplay is going to revolve around visiting ruined remains of buildings and areas that somehow survived the flooding. I've already come up with several location ideas such as islands, oil rigs, skyscrapers, and stuff like that, but I'd like to see what you guys think.

Does anyone have any ideas on some places you could visit after everything else is under a ton of water?

Comment: Compulsory reading is 'Flood' by Stephen Baxter, which describes exactly this scenario.

Comment: How deep is your water? Is it only the tops of mountain ranges like the Himalayas sticking out? Or is more like Earth's ice caps melting - the people in the Netherlands are homeless but people in Afghanistan haven't  been affected at all.

Answer (score 2):

Most landmarks are in densely populated areas relatively near the coast. The Statue of Liberty, Big Ben, even the Eiffel Tower. Those will be completely submerged before Samarkand (elevation 700 m) or Madrid (elevation 700 m) or Denver (elevation 1,600 m) get flooded.

Comment: Wow, interesting fact! I meant things in general that would still be visible above the water if there was no significant land still there (I'd assume everything still accessible would have to be built on the highest elevated surfaces if the planet was completely flooded).

Answer (score 1):

Things that float.

- Boats - military, cargo, cruise ships, personal watercraft of all sizes
- Moored barges that have broken free (most riverboat casinos in present-day real-world US)
- Slips and docks in areas with large tidal swings
- Wooden constructions of all sorts
- Sealed shipping containers